# Problem to convert a kivy file to a .apk file in Google Colab

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, kivy, google-colaboratory

I made a kivy app that I would like to convert to an .apk file to be able to use it in my android phone. I know that there is a lot of tutorials on the internet that explain how to do this in Google Colab. I used the instructions given in the article that you can find here : https://towardsdatascience.com/3-ways-to-convert-python-app-into-apk-77f4c9cd55af

The kivy file that I use is very simple, I made it just to try the way to convert it to an .apk file :

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        L = Label(text = "Hi !")
        return L

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()"
```

Yet, I cannot convert this script to .apk ...

When I execute the "!buildozer init" command, a script named "Buildozer.spec" was created in the current repertory of Colab, where I uploaded my kivy script. I only modified the title of my app and specified the kivy version that I wanted to use, i.e these very lines :

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = My App1

# (str) Package name
package.name = MyApp1

# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,kivy==1.9.1
```

I then execute the "!buildozer -v android debug" and after minutes waiting, I get the following error :

```
    Exception in thread background thread for pid 38813:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 1683, in wrap
    fn(*rgs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 2662, in background_thread
    handle_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 2349, in fn
    return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 905, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1: 

  RAN: /usr/bin/python3 '-cimport sys; from Cython.Compiler.Main import setuptools_main; sys.exit(setuptools_main());' ./kivy/graphics/opengl.pyx

  STDOUT:
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py:369: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: /content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/kivy/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/kivy/kivy/graphics/opengl.pyx
  tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
def glCheckFramebufferStatus(GLenum target):
    '''See: `glCheckFramebufferStatus() on Kronos website
    <http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glCheckFramebufferStatus.xml>`_
    '''
    cdef GLenum result
    result = c_opengl.CheckFramebufferStatus(target)
                    ^
------------------------------------------------------------

kivy/graphics/opengl.pyx:544:21: cimported module has no attribute 'CheckFramebufferStatus'


  STDERR:


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1294, in <module>
    main()
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/entrypoints.py", line 18, in main
    ToolchainCL()
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 728, in __init__
    getattr(self, command)(args)
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 151, in wrapper_func
    build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 213, in build_dist_from_args
    args, "ignore_setup_py", False
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 596, in build_recipes
    recipe.build_arch(arch)
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 1059, in build_arch
    self.build_cython_components(arch)
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 1084, in build_cython_components
    self.cythonize_build(env=env)
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipes/kivy/__init__.py", line 18, in cythonize_build
    super().cythonize_build(env, build_dir=build_dir)
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 1132, in cythonize_build
    self.cythonize_file(env, build_dir, join(root, filename))
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipes/kivy/__init__.py", line 39, in cythonize_file
    super().cythonize_file(env, build_dir, filename)
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 1123, in cythonize_file
    filename, *self.cython_args, _env=cyenv)
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/logger.py", line 167, in shprint
    for line in output:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 953, in next
    self.wait()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 879, in wait
    self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 905, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1: 

  RAN: /usr/bin/python3 '-cimport sys; from Cython.Compiler.Main import setuptools_main; sys.exit(setuptools_main());' ./kivy/graphics/opengl.pyx

  STDOUT:
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py:369: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: /content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/kivy/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/kivy/kivy/graphics/opengl.pyx
  tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
def glCheckFramebufferStatus(GLenum target):
    '''See: `glCheckFramebufferStatus() on Kronos website
    <http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glCheckFramebufferStatus.xml>`_
    '''
    cdef GLenum result
    result = c_opengl.CheckFramebufferStatus(target)
                    ^
------------------------------------------------------------

kivy/graphics/opengl.pyx:544:21: cimported module has no attribute 'CheckFramebufferStatus'


  STDERR:




# Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=MyApp1 --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy==1.9.1 --arch arm64-v8a --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21 --ignore-setup-py --debug
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     CUDNN_VERSION = '8.0.5.39'
#     PYDEVD_USE_FRAME_EVAL = 'NO'
#     LD_LIBRARY_PATH = '/usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64'
#     CLOUDSDK_PYTHON = 'python3'
#     LANG = 'en_US.UTF-8'
#     ENABLE_DIRECTORYPREFETCHER = '1'
#     HOSTNAME = 'ccdae318878b'
#     OLDPWD = '/'
#     CLOUDSDK_CONFIG = '/content/.config'
#     USE_AUTH_EPHEM = '1'
#     NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES = 'all'
#     DATALAB_SETTINGS_OVERRIDES = '{"kernelManagerProxyPort":6000,"kernelManagerProxyHost":"172.28.0.3","jupyterArgs":["--ip=172.28.0.2"],"debugAdapterMultiplexerPath":"/usr/local/bin/dap_multiplexer","enableLsp":true}'
#     ENV = '/root/.bashrc'
#     PAGER = 'cat'
#     NCCL_VERSION = '2.7.8'
#     TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH = 'true'
#     JPY_PARENT_PID = '41'
#     NO_GCE_CHECK = 'False'
#     PWD = '/content'
#     HOME = '/root'
#     LAST_FORCED_REBUILD = '20220628'
#     CLICOLOR = '1'
#     DEBIAN_FRONTEND = 'noninteractive'
#     LIBRARY_PATH = '/usr/local/cuda/lib64/stubs'
#     GCE_METADATA_TIMEOUT = '3'
#     GLIBCPP_FORCE_NEW = '1'
#     TBE_CREDS_ADDR = '172.28.0.1:8008'
#     TERM = 'xterm-color'
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     GCS_READ_CACHE_BLOCK_SIZE_MB = '16'
#     PYTHONWARNINGS = 'ignore:::pip._internal.cli.base_command'
#     MPLBACKEND = 'module://ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline'
#     CUDA_VERSION = '11.1.1'
#     NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES = 'compute,utility'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     PYTHONPATH = '/env/python'
#     NVIDIA_REQUIRE_CUDA = ('cuda>=11.1 brand=tesla,driver>=418,driver<419 '
 'brand=tesla,driver>=440,driver<441 brand=tesla,driver>=450,driver<451')
#     TBE_EPHEM_CREDS_ADDR = '172.28.0.1:8009'
#     COLAB_GPU = '0'
#     GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW = '1'
#     PATH = '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/opt/bin:/usr/local/nvidia/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/tools/node/bin:/tools/google-cloud-sdk/bin'
#     LD_PRELOAD = '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtcmalloc.so.4'
#     GIT_PAGER = 'cat'
#     _ = '/usr/local/bin/buildozer'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/root/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '27'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

If someone could help me, I'd be very thankful.

Comment: Try downgrading your Cython to 0.25.2 and rebuilding the apk.

Comment: Doesn't work ... When I tried the command "!pip install cython==0.25.2", I get the error : ERROR: Failed building wheel for cython. At the end, colab installed the version 0.29.30 of cython, and it doesn't work with this one unfortunately ...